# Deduce $a_1^2 - b_0^2 = 0$ from $a_0b_0 - a_1b_1 = 0,a_0b_1 + a_1b_0 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

For a certain application, I need to work with certain quadratic equations in **non-zero variables** that range on **an arbitrary field**. From:

$\begin{cases}a_0b_0 - a_1b_1 = 0 \\a_0b_1 + a_1b_0 = 0\end{cases}$

I need to deduce:

$a_1^2 - b_0^2 = 0$

Previous example worked by substitution of the first equation on the second, but in this example although my theorem prover is telling is correct the substitution method is not working. Is there a general strategy or tool that could solve this kind of problems?

Comment: Suppose $a_1=a_0=1$ and $b_1=b_0=0$.

Comment: Ah.  Missed that, sorry.

Comment: Can we assume that the field is commutative?

Comment: @ajotatxe yes, although the application are the fields underlying elliptic curves in Edwards form

Comment: The claim makes no sense, the equations are bi-linear, the scale of $a$ is decoupled from the scale of $b$ in the assumptions, while the claim contains such a coupling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both equations in a product of complex numbers
$$
(a_0+ia_1)(b_0+ib_1)=0.
$$
As the complex numbers are a field, one factor has to be zero.

---

Or inspired by that, but in purely real terms
\begin{align}
0&=(a_0b_0-a_1b_1)^2+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)^2\\
&=a_0^2b_0^2+a_1^2b_1^2+a_0^2b_1^2+a_1^2b_0^2\\
&=(a_0^2+a_1^2)(b_0^2+b_1^2)
\end{align}
and again one factor has to be zero.

Comment: this is very interesting. however, what if the underlying set is not the real numbers, but an arbitrary field?

Comment: Then you still have no non-trivial zero dividers, one factor has to be zero. Now the question is, does $a_0^2+a_1^2=0$ imply $a_0=a_1=0$. But that still does not lead to the claim.

Comment: By substitution you actually get that both factors are zero, but as you see this does not give the conclusion

Comment: How do you get that? What substitution?

Comment: From first equation you get $a_0 = a_1b_1 / b_0$ and from the second $a_0 = -a_1 b_0 / b_1$ and then you equal both equations and get $b_1^2 = -b_0^2$. You can also do this with $a_1$

Comment: Then $j=\frac{b_1}{b_0}$ is a complex unit in your field, $(b_0,b_1)=(\beta,j\beta)$ and then you get $(a_0,a_1)=(j\alpha,\alpha)$ so indeed both square sums are zero. However, there still does not follow a value determination of $\alpha112-\beta^2$.

Answer (score 0):

A specific counterexample:

in $\mathbb C$ let $a_0=2,a_1=2i$ and $b_0=i,b_1=1$.  Then $$a_0b_0-a_1b_1=2\times i-2i\times 1=0$$ and $$a_0b_1+a_1b_0=2\times 1+2i\times i=2-2=0$$  But $$a_1^2-b_0^2=-4+1\neq 0 $$